# Hive Query to select rows of same date and time as last row

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm looking for a Hive query that:
1) find "created_at" field in last record in a table
2) then select all records that has the same first 17 characters between their "created_at" field and the found one from the first step

- The reason for that: I want to show the records that are created at the same month, day, hour and minute ....and the created at field has also seconds at its end.

Comment: I have tried this command but It gives me parse error:

SELECT explode(split(concat_ws(' ', entities.hashtags.text), ' ')) AS word FROM 
(SELECT * FROM tweets,(SELECT *, row_number() over (ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS rn FROM tweets)tempTable3
        WHERE tempTable3.rn = 1 AND SUBSTR(tweets.created_at, 1, 17) = SUBSTR(tempTable3.created_at, 1, 17))
;

Comment: Mohamed, you should have added the table definition and a data sample including required results. Also, your attempted solution should go in the post and not as a comment, including the exact error you get.

Comment: The question itself does not make much sense. Why look for events " that are created at the same month, day, hour and minute" and not events preceding the last event, up to a minute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  *

from   (select  *
               ,rank() over 
                (
                    order by substr (created_at,1,17) desc
                ) as rnk

        from    tweets
        ) t

where   rnk = 1
;
```